# Find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(\sqrt n\cdot a_n)$.

Tags: real-analysis

> The sequence of real numbers $(a_n)$ is defined this way: $a_0=\frac {1}{2010}$ and $a_{n+1}=a_n-\arcsin(\sin^2a_n)$ for all $n\ge0$. 
>   Find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(\sqrt n\cdot a_n)$.

**My work so far:**

Sequence $a_n$ of decreasing, but positive, as $\sin a_n>\sin^2 a_n$. So there is a limit, and it is equal to zero. Apply Stolz theorem for sequences $na_n$:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{\frac1{a_n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1-n}{\frac1{a_{n+1}}-\frac1{a_n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\frac1{a_{n+1}}-\frac1{a_n}}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_n$ is a monotone decreasing sequence that converges to $0$.

Note that $$\frac{1}{a_{n+1}} = \frac{1}{a_n-\arcsin(\sin^2a_n)}=\frac{1}{a_n}\frac{1}{1-\frac{\arcsin(\sin^2a_n)}{a_n}}$$

Since $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1-\frac{\arcsin(\sin^2x)}{x}}=1+x+o(x)$,

$$\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{a_{n}}+1+o(1)$$

that is to say, $\displaystyle \frac{1}{a_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{a_{n}}\to 1$.

Cesaro mean theorem yields $\displaystyle \frac{1}{na_n}\to 1$,hence $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt n a_n}\to \infty$ and $\sqrt n a_n\to 0 $

Further asymptotic work shows that $\displaystyle a_n=\frac 1n - \frac{\ln n}{n^2} +o\left( \frac{\ln n}{n^2} \right)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: note that $(a_n)$ is strictly decrescent because $a_0=1/2010\in Q_1$ (first quadrant), then $0<\sin(a_0)<1$ and $\sin^2(a_0)<\sin(a_0)\to \arcsin \sin^2(a_0)<a_0\to a_1<a_0 and a_1\in Q_1$. By induction, $a_{k+1}<a_k$ and $a_k\in Q_1$ for all k.